# TemplateDoesNotExist Django. No encuentro el error

Tags: python, django

Estoy modificando un proyecto, y para mi al mover todo, no me he olvidado de nada, lo lei varias veces al codigo, pero no encuentro el error de que no encuentra el Template dentro de la aplicacion.

Demas esta decir, que en el settings.py del proyecto, la aplicaciòn se encuentra instalada correctamente.

ULRS.PY (PROYECTO)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('servicios/', include('servicios.urls')),
```

URLS.PY (DE LA APP servicios)

```
from django.urls import path    
from . import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.Servicios, name="servicios"),    
    ]
```

VIEWS.PY (DE LA APP servicios)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from servicios.models import servicios
# Create your views here.

def Servicios(request):
    
    #importamos todo lo que hay en servicios de admin.
    srv = servicios.objects.all()
    
    return render(request,"servicios/servicios.html", {"servicios" : srv})
```

Asi tengo mi directorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En tus settings.py como están configurados los templates? normalmente suele ser así ```'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]``` en tu caso es ```template```

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente la carpeta se pone como templates no template y dentro de esta ya se ponen los archivos html. Tu estas buscando en 'servicios/template/servicios/servicios.html' esto funcionaria si en tus DIRS pusiste 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'template')]

Para cerciorarte de esto te recomiendo revisar la configuración TEMPLATES del settings para ver que este correcta y este tomando los directorios correctos, puedes ver un poco mas sobre esto aquí: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines

Algo mas, cuando te da el error TemplateDoesNotExist ahí en el stacktrace te indica en que rutas busco el template servicios.html y con eso puedes verificar en donde intento buscar y compararlo con tu estructura de directorios y probablemente encuentre ahi el error. Si puedes compartir una captura con el error mucho mejor para poder diagnosticar bien el problema.